# Opening Ubuntu Error

Tags: windows-7, wubi, system-installation

I just downloaded ubuntu using wubi.exe on Windows 7. Whenever I start up my computer, I see the Windows Boot Manager with two options - Windows or Ubuntu. I try opening Ubuntu, which leads me to the Ubuntu purple and white loading screen, but after about a minute, I return back to the Windows Boot Manager. I can keep trying to open Ubuntu, and I get stuck in an infinite loop. Is there something wrong with my computer or did I do installation wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you had just installed wubi.exe it want help.
It just help to boot you to boot your Ubuntu.
You will need separate USB-flash stick or burned Cd of Ubuntu ISO to boot you further.
```